# Php pagination plugin

Tags: php, plugins, pagination

I'm seeking a php pagination plugin which

1. is customizable and doesn't have features to automatically create either DOMs or sentences
2. works fine with typical conditions like "limit", "total", "current page"...

I have seen several ones but they are too old. Has anyone seen recent one?

Comment: You need to clarify the question. Are you using any PHP framework? If yes, then the pagination feauture will most likely be there as a part of the framework, just read the documentation.
If no, it gets more difficult, because it must be able to work with different layers of the application (backend and frontend), which is hard without a framework.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, we use cakephp, but its component doesn't really fulfill our needs. For example it only works on controller, difficult to customize for seo, and some conditions of "->paginate()" are not supported. then we decided to try other plugin. We know that we should use the one included in the framework though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present all your data in table like format along with pagination

you can refer:

https://www.datatables.net/

this datatable has more features. In that pagination is also a part

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but sorry, I forgot to mention that we only look for a php pagination, not a javascript one. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: it's worth mentioning that data tables do not save page memory as pagination is created after all data is loaded. Imagine if you have 2000 records from the database, data tables will NOT help in this case. You would need to load a few data from PHP from the database not loading all data then optimizing the data with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Go with Pagerfanta. Meets your criteria plus:

- Adapters for range of Storage systems (doctrine, propel, elastica...)
- Actively developed
- Test covered

https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta

Comment: Thanks for your response. We considered your suggestion but decided to implement another plugin. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @naokinishikubo which plugin did you use?